# Compiling HTML file in Visual Studio 2015 community edition 2015

Tags: visual-studio

While compiling HTML file in Visual Studio 2015 when I click on debug button on top, I always get a dialogue box "Attach to process" like the one in the figure below. From there onwards nothing happens, means I can't see my HTML file compiled.
I have tried various solutions but nothing works

I actually don't know what to do with this dialogue box. 
Please help me out as soon as possible

[image]

Comment: What type of project did you create? you did create a new solution with a project in it, right?

Comment: I just chose  File->New->File-> Html page

Comment: That won't work since Visual Studio doesn't know what to do with your HTML file. What you should is create a new project (ex: New -> Project -> then choose something like ASP.NET). Check out the [docs](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/getting-started) to know what to do next.

Comment: HTML isn't compiled. Therefore, you can't compile it or execute it. You can load it in a web browser to view it.